# What's the difference between Abstract class and Virtual Class

Tags: apex, oop

Hi I'm just confused on how to to use Abstract class and Virtual. Can't seem to find any difference between them and what are some scenarios where in it's applicable to use abstract or virtual.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**tl;dr:**
Practically speaking, there isn't much difference. Don't worry about it too much. I tend to use `abstract` more often.

**long version**
The difference has historically been quite subtle.

- Both `virtual` and `abtract` classes allow you to extend the class (i.e. create child classes that inherit non-private methods and variables)
- A `virtual` class can be instantiated directly, whereas an `abstract` class cannot
- Both `virtual` and `abstract` classes can contain `virtual` methods (`virtual` methods can have a default implementation that is inherited by child classes, whereas `abstract` methods can only be signatures, and *must* be implemented in child classes)
- Only `abstract` classes may contain `abstract` methods

In practice, I haven't seen much practical difference between the two. The `abstract` and `virtual` modifiers, in my mind, are more important for methods (as opposed to classes).

If you're going to use a class that's either `abstract` or `virtual`, I've found that I'm more likely to be using that class as more of a *contract* (i.e. when you use this class, we guarantee that variables `a`, `b`, and `c` will be available for use, along with methods `x`, `y`, and `z`), rather than a *specialization* that is used apart, *distinctly*, from its parent class.

This mostly comes down to the philosophy of object-oriented design that I have learned as part of my professional career. To put it into a single sentence: If you're relying on something having a specific implementation (i.e. you *need* to use a `square` or a `rectangle` instead of a more general `parallelogram`), then you can probably improve your solution.

The general idea is that by relying on *contracts* rather than *implementations*, your code is *more resistant to change*. Put another way, by relying on contracts, a change to a specific implementation of that contract is contained to one or two classes (as opposed to making a change in one class ending up requiring a change to *many* other classes).

So for that goal (relying on a contract more than an implementation), I find myself using `abstract` classes more often because I tend to want the consumers of my code to use specific, specialized implementations (to suit the task at hand) rather than a general "catch-all" implementation. To that end, `abstract`, with it's inability to be directly constructed, is more useful to me.

Comment: "Both virtual and abstract classes can contain virtual or abstract methods" -- Nope, only abstract classes can contain abstract methods. The point of a virtual class is that it can operate without requiring subclassing.

Comment: @sfdcfox duly noted, answer updated.

Answer (score 25):

Abstract classes allow you to define "partial" classes. They implement some sort of algorithm that can be used by other classes, but do not represent a full implementation by themselves. For example, my [AWS](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/92cf05807ac4becbd21f) example provides a class that handles calculating parameters, etc (over 200 lines of default functionality), but does not directly do anything with AWS; the remainder is handled by child classes to connect to a specific service. Note that abstract classes could be implemented by interfaces or helper classes, but make the code more compact and generally legible.

Virtual classes allow you to define "full" classes. They implement all of the necessary functionality to operate on their own, but can be extended by child classes in order to allow customization of its behavior. This is far less common in every day Apex Code than abstract classes, but is useful when you have large classes that provide tons of default functionality, but may require overriding just one or two methods. In Java, these are used all over the place, for example, a [WindowAdapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowAdapter.html) that can listen to about a dozen events, but can have just one method overridden so the developer doesn't have to write implementations for all of the methods.

Unlike interfaces and abstract methods, virtual classes allow you to override just one single method if you want, without having to implement all of the methods. For example, a Trigger Handler factory might use a virtual class to provide default methods (e.g. beforeInsert, afterInsert, beforeUpdate...), but allow the developer to override just one method instead of a dozen.

Comment: Thank you for the example. Really helped a lot, things are getting clearer now.

Comment: If you want to do true unit testing on a class basis, rather than heavier tests that are more like integration tests (depending on other classes to do a lot of work), you might like to make the majority of your classes virtual and use virtual methods instead of static ones. That way, with an appropriate dependency injection mechanism (quite possible in Apex), you can isolate the class to be tested from other classes by mocking out those other classes (essentially overriding the various methods in the dependency classes).

Answer (score 18):

The [Apex Class Definition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_defining.htm) resource from the Apex Developer Guide may provide some illumination.

In summary, `virtual` classes *permits* subclassing and method overriding. However, a `virtual` class does implement functionality itself and can be instantiated and used directly.

Conversely, `abstract` classes *must* be subclassed and have methods overridden to provide functionality. `abstract` classes cannot be instantiated or used themselves; they are more fully "abstract base classes".

Answer (score 16):

I see that is quite an old thread, but I have some brief descriptions, which can be helpful for future use.

***Interface***

- To create an interface we need to use interface keyword.
- Interface can
  provide a layer of abstraction to your code.
- Interface is an apex
  the class that can contain only method signature, as a result, the body
  of each method must be empty.
- An apex class that is using the
  interface **must** implement all methods listed in the interface.
- Interface separates the specific method declaration from its
  implementation. Therefore you can have different implementations for
  the same method. The concept behind Interface is that you can change
  the implementation without changing your whole code. Consequently, the method
  signature (return type, parameters) is always the same.
- Interface
  can be treated as a new data type. In Apex we have a few predefined
  interfaces like String, Integer, Double, etc. In other words
  implementation of those methods can be changed (by Salesforce) without
  changes in our code – that’s the power of interface! e.g.:
  String.isBlank(‘Test’); We know method signature (public static
  Boolean isBlank(String inputString)), but we don’t know
  implementation layer.

***Abstract***

- To create an abstract class, we need to use an abstract definition modifier.
- Allow extending the child's class.
- Abstract class can contain methods signed as abstract, to clarify, it is a method that has only a signature (body is not defined).
- Child class **must** implement all methods declared as abstract!
- Abstract class can also include other methods, which have logic.
  To allow child class access those methods use protected or public keywords.
- **Cannot** be initialize directly: new TestAbstractClass();
- Abstract class can contain both virtual and abstract methods.
- Abstract class is some kind of “partial” class.
  Therefore, some methods are implemented, and some needs to be implemented by the child class.
- virtual methods can be overridden, but this is not mandatory.

***Virtual***

- To create a virtual class, we need to use a virtual definition modifier.
- You can extend a class to provide more sophisticated behavior.
- Class that extends another class inherits all the methods and properties of the extended class.
- Methods declared as virtual can be overridden.
  In other words, overriding a virtual method allows you to provide a different implementation for an existing method.
- A class can only extend one other class, but it can implement more than one interface.
- Virtual class can be initialize directly **new TestVirtualClass()**;
- You can use **virtual** or regular methods.
- Virtual class is some kind of “full” class.
  All methods are implemented but can be overridden by the child class.

| Feature | Interface | Abstract | Virtual |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Keyword** | ***`interface`*** e.g `public interface MyInterface {}` | **`abstract`** e.g `public abstract class MyAbstractClass {}` | ***`virtual`*** e.g `public virtual class MyVirtualClass {}` |
| **How to use?** | By ***`implements`*** e.g `public class MyChildClass implements MyInterface {}` | By **`extends`** e.g `public class MyChildClass extends MyAbstractClass {}` | By **`extends`** e.g `public class MyChildClass extends MyVirtualClass {}` |
| **Type of Methods** | Only method signature e.g `String getFullName(String firstName, String lastName);` | Can contains `abstract`, `virtual` and implements own methods. e.g `abstract String getFullName(String firstName, String lastName);` `public virtual String getFullName(String firstName, String lastName);` | Can contains only `virual` and implements onw methods e.g `public virtual String getFullName(String firstName, String lastName);` |
| **Implement Parent Mehthods** | ✅ All interface's methods needs to be implemented | ✅ Only methods signed as `abstract` | ❌ Cannot force child class to implements parent methods |
| **Override Parent Methods** | ❌ Interface doesn't contain logic to override | ✅ Only methods signed as `virtual` | ✅ Only methods signed as `virtual` |
| **Has basic logic?** | ❌ Interface contains only method signature | ✅ Methods signed as `virual` and inner methods can contain basic logic | ✅ Methods signed as `virual` and inner methods can contain basic logic |
| **Can be initialized directly?** | ❌ <s>new MyInterface();</s> | ❌ <s>new MyAbstractClass();</s> | ✅ new MyVirtualClass(); |
| **Pros** | ✅ New layer of abstraction. ✅ Interface can be treated as a new data type. ✅ Logic behind the interface can be changed without changes in related classes. ✅ We program to interfaces, not implementations. Code doesn't have reference to specific classes. ✅ Child class is forced to implement the interface's method (Guarantee specific logic). ✅ Child class can implement many interfaces. | ✅ Abstract class can store common logic (avoid redundancy) ✅ Child class can be forced to implement some (signed as `abstract`) methods. ✅ Child class can override some (signed as `virtual`) methods. ✅ Basic logic can be provided by abstract class inner methods. (`private`, `protected`, `public`) ✅ Easy to update common code for all child methods. Just update code in abstract class. | ✅ virtual class can be treated as a base class with base logic, which should be accessed by all child classes. ✅ Virtual class can be initialized direct ✅ Child class can override some (signed as `virtual` methods) ✅ Easy to update common code for all child method. Just update code in a virtual class. Basic logic can be provided by abstract class inner methods. (`private`, `protected`, `public`) |
| **Cons** | ❌ Hard to add or change the interface's methods, because all classes that implement the interface need to be changed as well. ❌ Apex class needs to implement all interface methods even if it's not relevant. | ❌ Cannot be initialized directly. ❌ Apex class needs to implement all `abstract` methods even if it's not relevant. ❌ Child class can be only extended by one parent class. | ❌ Cannot force child class to implement parent method (`abstract` cannot be used) ❌ Child class can be only extended by one parent class. |
| **Goal** | To create a new layer of abstraction | To provide a kind of "partial" class with common logic | To provide a kind of "full" class with base logic |

More details, examples of usage, and use cases can find
https://beyondthecloud.dev/blog/abstract-virtual-interface-in-apex